# Number of elements of a coset of a group of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

Fix $r$ and $q$ primes with $r$ less than $q$. Find minimal $k$ such that $r\ |\ q^k-1$ and construct $F_{q^k}$ a finite field (in this case $F_{q^k}$ contains all the $r$-th roots of unity).

Define the coset of elements $(F^*_{q^k})^r = \{u^r\ |\ u \in F^*_{q^k} \}$.

**Question.** What is the cardinality of  $(F^*_{q^k})^r$ ?

I would say it is $\frac{q^k-1}{r}$ but any hints on proving it ?

Comment: What is the notation $F^*_{q^k}$? Is this supposed to denote the multiplicative group?

Comment: Yes, without zero (of course without zero)

Comment: Recall that $F^*_{q^k}$ is a cyclic group so $(F^*_{q^k})^r$ is a subgroup of index $r$. Hence it has $(q^k-1)/r$ elements.

Comment: That was also my thinking @Crostul, but why the index of $(F^*_{q^k})^r$ is $r$ ?

Comment: $x^{q^k-1}-1$ has at most $q^k$ roots in the field $\overline{\mathbf{F}_q}$, and since $\mathbf{F}_{q^k}^*$ has order $q^k-1$, those roots are exactly the elements of $\mathbf{F}_{q^k}^*$. Also there are some elements which are roots of $x^{q^k-1}-1$ but not of $x^d-1$ for any $d | q^k-1$, thus those elements are of order $q^k-1$  and $\mathbf{F}_{q^k}^*$ is cyclic with $q^k-1$ elements. Thus $(\mathbf{F}_{q^k}^*)^r$ is cyclic of order $\frac{q^k-1}{r}$ and has index $r$.